# cumulative sum by conditions and group

Tags: r

May be this question already addressed and answered in SO, but I couldn't able to find out.

I'm an newbee in R and computing cumulative sum with conditions on a very large data frame.

Look at the below example.

```
c_id    s_id    dest_id type  time_transaction  refid  price_c_id
11      A   issue   21.11.11 06:00      3
9608            B       issue   21.11.11 06:12      2
31300           C       issue   21.11.11 09:50      6
112     D   issue   22.11.11 12:03      1
13      B   issue   22.11.11 12:40      2
14      A   issue   22.11.11 12:54      1
9608    B   C   prop    22.11.11 18:40  177 2
125     A   issue   23.11.11 04:06      1
145     A   issue   24.11.11 09:44      3
144     D   issue   24.11.11 10:32      6
3       B   issue   24.11.11 10:35      4
2       C   issue   24.11.11 10:58      5
1300    C   B   resp    24.11.11 19:12  177 6
1111        A   issue   25.11.11 07:03      8
1111    A   B   prop    25.11.11 07:14  114 8
12      D   issue   25.11.11 08:01      1
16      C   issue   25.11.11 08:03      1
13  B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 2
3   B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 4
9       C   issue   26.11.11 14:12      2
2   C   B   resp    26.11.11 19:54  121 5
6       B   issue   26.11.11 20:09      3
1300    B   A   resp    27.11.11 08:06  114 6
```

It requires to know:

1) the cumulative sum by condition at time of proposing for 
proposer (here: B) and for responder (here C)

Cumulative sum of price_c_id for B at time of proposing; and sum of price_c_id for C (who is responder) at time of proposing.

What I did is:

```
DT[,Cum.Sum:=cumsum(Sum), by = list (s_id, dest_id)].
```

But I don't know how to restrict the sum by type == "prop".
What should I get is. In the row of "prop" for B: 4 and for C: 6 (two columns).

2) the cumulative sum by condition at time of responding for 
proposer (here: B) and for responder (here C)

What should I get is. In the row of "rep" for B: 8 (4+4) and for C: 11 (6+5) (two columns). The responder answers with time-delay. So the portfolio (price_c_id) of proposer or responder might be decrease or increase in meantime.

3) the result of transaction:

B gave 6 and got 2. 
C got 6 and gave 2.

So the result of transaction is 12 (8-2+6) for B and 7 (11-6+2) for C. See 3 last columns in the answer.

I would appreciate when the result looks more or less like this.
Is there a smart way to do this three steps?

```
c_id    s_id    de_id   type    time          refid p_c_id  s_p1    s_r1    s_p2    s_r2    s_p3    s_r3
11      A   issue   21.11.11 06:00      3                       
9608        B   issue   21.11.11 06:12      2                       
1300        C   issue   21.11.11 09:50      6                       
112     D   issue   22.11.11 12:03      1                       
13      B   issue   22.11.11 12:40      2                       
14      A   issue   22.11.11 12:54      1                       
9608    B   C   prop    22.11.11 18:40  177 2   4   6               
125     A   issue   23.11.11 04:06      1                       
145     A   issue   24.11.11 09:44      3                       
144     D   issue   24.11.11 10:32      6                       
3       B   issue   24.11.11 10:35      4                       
2       C   issue   24.11.11 10:58      5                       
1300    C   B   resp    24.11.11 19:12  177 6           8     11    12  7 
1111        A   issue   25.11.11 07:03      8                       
1111    A   B   prop    25.11.11 07:14  114 8   16  12              
12      D   issue   25.11.11 08:01      1                       
16      C   issue   25.11.11 08:03      1                       
13  B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 2   12  8               
3   B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 4   s.o.    s.o.                
9       C   issue   26.11.11 14:12      2                       
2   C   B   resp    26.11.11 19:54  121 5           12  10  11  11 
6       B   issue   26.11.11 20:09      3                       
1300    B   A   resp    27.11.11 08:06  114 6           16  14  14  16
```

Comment: I think a `dput()` of your original data frame/data table would help.

Comment: Learn to format the data properly while posting on SO. It does give a preview of your post while editing. Tag them properly. You seem to be using `data.table`. Provide the data in a reproducible form `?dput`. Also take your time and frame your sentences properly/clearly.

Comment: Where is the variable `Sum` coming from? Furthermore the `price_c_id` seems to be empty in many the data lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict calculations to particular lines by using a logical argument to the "i" position of

```
DT[i,j, ...]
```

First question;I'm guessing you mean to get the cumsum of the `price_c_id` value rather than `Sum`. Try:

```
DT[type=="prop", Cum.Sum:=cumsum(price_c_id), by = list (s_id, dest_id) ]
```

I don't understand the second and thord question. Are we having trouble with lack a shared first language and a translation difficulty?

The data object was created with ... PLEASE check to see if you have a tab separated file and did different input. Looks like there is massive misregistration:

```
dat <- read.table(text=
"c_id    s_id    dest_id type  time_transaction  refid  price_c_id
11      A   issue   21.11.11 06:00      3
9608            B       issue   21.11.11 06:12      2
31300           C       issue   21.11.11 09:50      6
112     D   issue   22.11.11 12:03      1
13      B   issue   22.11.11 12:40      2
14      A   issue   22.11.11 12:54      1
9608    B   C   prop    22.11.11 18:40  177 2
125     A   issue   23.11.11 04:06      1
145     A   issue   24.11.11 09:44      3
144     D   issue   24.11.11 10:32      6
3       B   issue   24.11.11 10:35      4
2       C   issue   24.11.11 10:58      5
1300    C   B   resp    24.11.11 19:12  177 6
1111        A   issue   25.11.11 07:03      8
1111    A   B   prop    25.11.11 07:14  114 8
12      D   issue   25.11.11 08:01      1
16      C   issue   25.11.11 08:03      1
13  B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 2
3   B   C   prop    25.11.11 08:08  121 4
9       C   issue   26.11.11 14:12      2
2   C   B   resp    26.11.11 19:54  121 5
6       B   issue   26.11.11 20:09      3
1300    B   A   resp    27.11.11 08:06  114 6 ", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
 DT <- data.table(dat)
```